# $(4x)^{\log_{10}5}=(5x)^{\log_{10}7}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given that $$(4x)^{\log_{10}5}=(5x)^{\log_{10}7}$$

Find $x$.

I've been trying many ways to solve it, but it ended up not correct. Hope someone can give some hints on it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using logarithms you can use this approach:
$$(4x)^{\log_{10}5}=(5x)^{\log_{10}7} \Rightarrow \frac{4^{\log_{10}5}}{5^{\log_{10}7}}=x^{\log_{10}7-\log_{10}5} \Rightarrow$$
$$x=\left( \frac{4^{\log_{10}5}}{5^{\log_{10}7}}\right)^{\frac{1}{\log_{10}7-\log_{10}5}}$$

Answer (score 3):

taking the logarithm on both sides we get
$$\log_{10} 5(\ln(4)+\ln(x))=\log_{10} 7(\ln(5)+\ln(x))$$
now set $$t=\ln(x)$$ and solve a linear equation

Answer (score 1):

The equation is equivalent to
$$10^{(\log_{10}(4x))(\log_{10}5)}=10^{(\log_{10}(5x))(\log_{10}7)}$$
i.e.
\begin{align*}
[\log_{10}(4x)]\log_{10}5&=[\log_{10}(5x)]\log_{10}7\\[3pt]
(\log_{10}4+\log_{10}x)\log_{10}5&=(\log_{10}5+\log_{10}x)\log_{10}7\\[3pt]
(\log_{10}5-\log_{10}7)\log_{10}x&=(\log_{10}7-\log_{10}4)\log_{10}5\\[3pt]
\log_{10}(\tfrac57)\log_{10}x&=\log_{10}(\tfrac74)\log_{10}5\\[3pt]
\log_{10}x&=\frac{\log_{10}(\frac74)\log_{10}5}{\log_{10}(\frac57)}
\end{align*}
Then $$x=10^{\frac{\log_{10}(\frac74)\log_{10}5}{\log_{10}(\frac57)}}=5^{\log_{5/7}(7/4)}$$